# How to modify an existing PDF file contents in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdf, itext

I am using a Spring Boot application and I need to dynamically populate the blanks in an existing PDF using the values from the database. I have attached the image of the PDF for your reference.

I want to know the best practice to do so. Please guide me.

[Image of the PDF which I want to dynamically populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfrSJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please describe technically what those rectangles in your image are - or better, share your example file.

Comment: Rectangle box are nothing but just a design which i had given in place for input tag. i want to populate the dynamic values in those rectangles.

Comment: Would it be possible to use AcroForm form fields instead? If you insist on using arbitrary rectangles, you'll make the code replacing them with some content unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: yes i can use that. Plesse help me out regarding the strategy and library whjich i should use to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: thank you everyone for your quick responses. however, please upvote my question if you can as stack overflow has limited my ask of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used now Itext version 7. Where i have created the exact replica of the existing PDF using Itext table cells.

When you are writing the generation code itself in JAVA then there is no problem in mapping the data into the same.